# Print Git Repo Version

Tags: git, version

I am using Git to maintain a numerical solver that requires inputs from external text files.

With the growth of functionality, the new version of solver requires more input data than the previous versions. This means that parsing error may occur if one uses the latest solver to run a old inputs.

What I wish to do is for the compiled solver to be able to print its version number (e.g., the output from **git rev-parse HEAD**) to the output file. This will be extremely useful since we have large number of past simulation cases.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Git provides a "hook" system, Your best bet is to use a script in there

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks

post-commit sounds like your best bet, This will allow the update of the commit version to be used in the compiled version.

Though it also seems you could trivially add this with a `make` script ?